# 2 сервера, apache + nginx и NAT Mikrotik

Tags: nginx, apache, mikrotik, nat

Встала задача запустить два веб-сервера в одной сети.
Сервер 1 Apache - откливается на      madmentat.ru
Сервер 2 Nginx  - откликается на mail.madmentat.ru
На Микротике проброшены порты 80 и 443. При обращении из глобальной сети запрос идет на один из них, на тот что выше в таблице правил Firewall-NAT, а тот что ниже просто не работает, ничего не грузится. Как сделать чтобы были доступны оба сервера?

Comment: На уровне сети это невозможно. Нужно или ставить третий веб-сервер, который будет направлять запрос на один из первых двух серверов в зависимости от домена, или настраивать один из этих веб-серверов на перенаправление на другой веб-сервер

Comment: Да, чистый нат поможет только в случае, когда порты разные. Если порты одинаковые, надо поднимать проксирующий nginx который по *доменному имени* будет форвардить запросы на разные серваки внутри

Comment: Почему именно Nginx? А у Apache есть такой функционал?

Comment: Есть, но Apache по своей архитектуре более медленный и nginx для такого подходит лучше

Comment: Вам точно нужны для этого разные машины? Разместить два разных сервера на одной почему-либо не хочется?

Comment: Не хочется по религиозным причинам. Ситуация такая: комп с apache - это Odroid XU4, одноплатник на arm-архитектуре. Он не шибко шустрый, к тому же я не могу туда воткнуть лишнюю плашку оперативки и т. д. Там, помимо пары сайтиков, работает NAS, всякие ftp, samba и другие сервисы, которые не должны упасть в ходе каких-то экспериментов. А та машина, где планируется Nginx - будет выделана практически только под почту, сам веб-сервер ей нужен для веб-морды. Я как-то настраивал iRedMail, так вот после этого у меня начались проблемы, в результате которых пришлось переустановить систему.

Answer (score 2):

Проброс сделайте на nginx. На нем добавьте виртуальный сервер

```
server {

    server_name madmentat.ru;

    root /var/www/;
    index index.html;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://madmentat.local/;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;

        # Allows websockets over HTTPS.
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host:$server_port;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/madmentat.ru/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/madmentat.ru/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
```

ssl офлоад если нужен, то переносится на nginx. если не нужен, то уберите строчки.